# SQLiteDatabase.insert not inserting values, debugger not reaching onCreate

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've created a database for a school assignment which inserts values in onCreate. The database is created, however, the values aren't inserted.

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bdproduits";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS produits(" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "nomProduit TEXT,"+
                "categorie TEXT,"+
                "prixUnitaire REAL,"+
                "uniteEnStock INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(sql);

        //db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("nomProduit","Chai");
        cv.put("categorie","BOISSONS");
        cv.put("prixUnitaire", "90.0");
        cv.put("uniteEnStock","39");
        db.insert("produits",null, cv);
        

        cv.put("nomProduit","CHANG");
        cv.put("categorie","BOISSONS");
        cv.put("prixUnitaire", "95.0");
        cv.put("uniteEnStock","17");
        db.insert("produits",null, cv);

        cv.put("nomProduit","Aniseed Syrup");
        cv.put("categorie","CONDIMENTS");
        cv.put("prixUnitaire", "50.0");
        cv.put("uniteEnStock","13");
        db.insert("produits",null, cv);

        cv.put("nomProduit","Chef Anton's Cajun seasoning");
        cv.put("categorie","CONDIMENTS");
        cv.put("prixUnitaire", "110.0");
        cv.put("uniteEnStock","53");
        db.insert("produits",null, cv);

        cv.put("nomProduit","Chef Anton's gumbo mix");
        cv.put("categorie","CONDIMENTS");
        cv.put("prixUnitaire", "106.75");
        cv.put("uniteEnStock","0");
        db.insert("produits",null, cv);

        cv.put("nomProduit","Grandma's Boysenberry Spread");
        cv.put("categorie","CONDIMENTS");
        cv.put("prixUnitaire", "106.75");
        cv.put("uniteEnStock","0");
        db.insert("produits",null, cv);

        cv.put("nomProduit","Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears");
        cv.put("categorie","SECS");
        cv.put("prixUnitaire", "150.0");
        cv.put("uniteEnStock","15");
        db.insert("produits",null, cv);

        cv.put("nomProduit","Northwoods Cranberry Sauce");
        cv.put("categorie","CONDIMENTS");
        cv.put("prixUnitaire", "200.0");
        cv.put("uniteEnStock","6");
        db.insert("produits",null, cv);

        cv.put("nomProduit","Mishi Kobe Niku");
        cv.put("categorie","VIANDES");
        cv.put("prixUnitaire", "485.0");
        cv.put("uniteEnStock","29");
        db.insert("produits",null, cv);

        cv.put("nomProduit","Ikura");
        cv.put("categorie","POISSONS_FRUITS_DE_MER");
        cv.put("prixUnitaire", "155.0");
        cv.put("uniteEnStock","11");
        db.insert("produits",null, cv);

        //close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS produits");
            onCreate(db);
    }
   }
```

ContentValues are given the exact same keys as the database on each insert, that's what leaves me puzzled. I've noticed the debugger doesn't seems to reach it when I open the application if I put a breakpoint.

Ps: Yes, the database's keys are in French, I'm forced to.

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: Change the version of your database and rerun.